# IIS outboud rule to match the non-existance of substring in file name

Tags: javascript, regex, iis, configuration

I have the following IIS configuration which forces PDFs to be downloaded as files in the browser instead of opening in the browser window.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="Force Download for PDFs" preCondition="FileIsPDF">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content-Disposition" pattern=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*)\\([^/]+)\.pdf$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="attachment; filename={C:2}.pdf" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="FileIsPDF">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.pdf$" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However I need it to not apply if the file name is xxx_print.pdf, in other words I want the above rule to match all .pdf files except those that have _print at the end of the file name.
How is this possible?  Needs to work for IIS7 and above.

Note you may be able to answer this without an understanding of IIS if you know how to use javascript's regular expression to match a string without a particular substring.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I just had to add another condition to the rule with the negate="true" attribute:

```
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*)\\([^/]+)_print\.pdf$" negate="true" />
```